# Добавление переменных в бд sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть парсер, к нему пытаюсь сделать бд с помощью sqlite3, таблицу создает, но данные в нее не вносит.
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Binding 1 has no name, but you supplied a dictionary (which has only names). - вот такую ошибку он мне пишет.
Это мой первый опыт создания бд, не судите строго.)
p.s. - перегуглил на столько, что голова кипит.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('hab_data.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executescript("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS hab_data (title TEXT, URL TEXT, USER_NAME TEXT, USER_LINK TEXT, R_DATE TEXT)")

# код парсера

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO hab_data (title, URL, USER_NAME, USER_LINK, R_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (hab))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта как задавать параметры для запроса:

- неименованные параметры
- именованные параметры

### Неименованные параметры

В этом случае в запросе нужно использовать знаки вопроса на местах параметров, а значения передавать вторым параметом в `execute` в виде списка или кортежа. Подстановка будет произведена по порядку, т.е. вместо первого знака вопроса - первый параметр и т.д.:

```
hab_title = 'some-title'
hab_url = 'http://some.url'
...
cursor.execute(
   "INSERT INTO hab_data (title, URL, USER_NAME, USER_LINK, R_DATE) "
   "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
   (hab_title, hab_url, user_name, user_link, rdate)
)
```

тут `hab_title`, `hab_url`, и т.п. это переменные которые содержат значения соответствующих полей.

### Именованные параметры

В этом случае параметры в запросе задаются на знаками вопроса с помощью синтаксиса, который позволяет задать имя параметра. Второй агрумент `execute` в этом случае - это `dict` со значениями параметров.

```
hab = {
  'titiel': 'some-title',
  'url': 'http://some.url',
  ...
}
cursor.execute(
   "INSERT INTO hab_data (title, URL, USER_NAME, USER_LINK, R_DATE) "
   "VALUES (:title, :url, :username, :userlink, :rdate)",
   hab
)
```

### executemany

Если вы используете `executemany`, то вторым параметром нужно передавать список, каждый элемент которого можно было бы передать в `execute`.

И те же самые правила, если используете неименованные параметры, то элементом списка должен быть кортеж/список, в котором элементов сколько же, сколько знаков вопроса в тексте запроса.

Если используете неименованные параметры, то элементами должны быть словари.

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться.)